# python Matplotlib tight_layout() never work well

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, layout, data-visualization

**Summary:** I want to use `Matplotlib.tight_layout()` to automatically optimize the layout of figures that contains any number of subfigures with 2D `numpy.array`.

**Example:**
Here is an example (the data can be accessed from http://www.filedropper.com/fmap). I want to plot the feature map of an CNN layer (later I want to make this automatic, so the code can plot feature maps of any layer from any model). Here I only show the code for one layer for demonstration:

```
fmap.shape # (1, 64, 64, 128)
square1 = int(round(math.sqrt(fmap.shape[-1])/8)*8) # 8
square2 = int(fmap.shape[-1]/square1) # 16

ix = 1
for _ in range(square1):
    for _ in range(square2):
        # specify subplot and turn of axis
        ax = plt.subplot(square1, square2, ix)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        # plot filter channel in grayscale
        plt.imshow(fmap[0, :, :, ix-1], cmap='gray')
        ix += 1

# show the figure
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The plot is shown as:
[image]
The space between subfigures and the margin are quite random, as can be seen from feature maps of different layers (the number of subplot differs):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest reviewing [matplotlib: Tight Layout guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html) & [`matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html). Try using the `rect` parameter. It's expected that the padding is dependant upon the number of subplots and the figure size and will be different depending on the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have been playing with those parameters quite a lot. But there is no universal way to make them work. Please help if you have more experience on how to choose these parameters. The things I have tried include, h_adjust, w_adjust, rect, fig_size, etc.

Comment: It is also important to note that you are using `imshow` which defaults to `aspect='equal'`, always showing square images when x and y dimensions are equal.  If you really want tight layout, you either need to set a suitable figure width and height, or use `imshow(..., aspect='auo')` (which stretches the images to fit into the desired layout).

Answer (score 3):

You can set figure layout parameters with [`subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

### Basic Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(N, N)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5

fig, ax = plt.subplots(N, N)

plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.1, top = 0.9, right = 0.9, bottom = 0.1, hspace = 0.5, wspace = 0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To avoid making too many attempts to set the values of `left`, `top`, etc..., I suggest you to plot a figure, press the *Configure subplots* button:

[image]

and manually change the values of those six parameters, until you find a configuration that satisfies you. At this point, you can set those six values directly via code using `subplots_adjust`.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for providing a solution. That can only partially address my question, as I have quite some figures to plot and really need it to be fully-automatic. Your answer is a nice workaround, but still needs some trial-and-error.